Solvers for finding a solution that satisfies a large system of constraints
please advise automated solvers for solving the following problem:
There are about 12500 binary variables and a system of linear constraints on them - about 800 linear equalities and 37000 linear inequalities. I have not encountered such problems in my work before, it is similar to the MILP problem, but without the objective function. I tried using Gurobi with the objective function '0' to obtain a particular solution for a smaller model of my task (800 binary variables, 200 linear equaalities and 2000 linear inequalities), everything worked out momentally, but for the model described before, Gurobi does not cope in an acceptable time.
Are there any solvers for this problem? Ideally, to find all solutions (there won't be many, judging by the small model, about several hundred).
If it helps, I can reduce the number of variables to 192 (also binary), but then the constraint system will be reduced to a system of about 800 quadratic equalities. Judging by the reduced model, all solutions of this system will have same Hamming weight. I cannot provide a description of the system because it has a very complex structure, I wanted to ask about the means for solving it 'in general', if they exist.

Can you please explain why your reduced model is not desirable? The original problem is truly massive, I don't think any solver could do anything interesting unless the problem has a very exploitable structure. Another option is to come up with a heuristic yourself, but I understand this may not be a possibility.

Honestly, I don't know, maybe the reduced model has solutions that can be found heuristically, but I couldn't. Initially, I had a reduced system, but then I moved from quadratic equalities to a linear system of inequalities by introducing additional variables, as suggested in the answer to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42537439/gurobi-lp-file-syntax. Thank you!

Ah okay, I understand what's going on now (as a side note, the question you shared is from 2017, almost 8 years ago. What was true then might not be true now). I would try setting a higher emphasis on presolving. Are there independent systems in your problem? Like, clusters of variables that only interact between themselves?

Yes, if for each equation we consider the set of variables that participate in it, some of the resulting sets intersect by a large number of variables, and the other part - by a small number. I used this to solve one of these systems, tried all the solutions of one equation completely, and then tried the minimum number of variables to filter out solutions for other equations, and so on step by step. However, such a solution takes a lot of time and resources (I described it in the comments to the answer below), perhaps universal solvers, which are clearly better optimized, will do a better job.

Since it is a feasibility problem with strictly binary variables, you might try a constraint programming solver. There are some open source solvers (and modeling packages), but for your larger problem I suspect you would want a commercial version. I'm familiar with IBM's CP Optimizer, but I believe there are other alternatives.
If some of your equalities and inequalities have specific underlying structures (such as an "all different" constraint), a constraint solver which supports those types of constraints will be able to exploit the problem structure to speed things up. Worst case, any CP solver should be able to handle binary variables and linear constraints. Whether they will be able to solve your larger problem in acceptable time is an empirical question, as is the ability to generate all or even multiple feasible solutions.

Doesn't Bordeaux, Lucas, et al. "The complexity of integer bound propagation." Journal of Artificial Intelligence Research 40 (2011): 657-676. apply here? (In particular we show that this fixpoint computation is in fact NP-complete, even when restricted to binary linear constraints.) Gecode's docs also say Howewer, the complexity of domain propagation for linear is exponential, hence it is a good idea to avoid posting linear constraints as much as possible.

NP-completeness is an asymptotic result, so I generally don't pay much attention to it. The fundamental question is whether an approach solves the problem with its given (fixed) dimensions or not. I am prepared to believe that avoiding linear constraints might be a good idea in CP, but that does not rule out CP as a candidate approach. Also, since the variables are binary, it may be possible to rewrite some of those linear constraints as logical constraints (implications, cover constraints, all different, ...).

Thank you for your answers and suggestions, I will try. I have already obtained some results on solving systems of the described type. The global task is as follows: to find a mathematical object, a complex system is composed, described in the post. In total, about 16 million different systems can be composed, a mathematical object exists if it is possible to find a solution for at least one of the systems.

I have already managed to show that one system has no solutions. For this, I wrote a program in C myself, but it requires a server with 128 GB of memory and several processors to run, the solution itself takes about two weeks and uses the features of the system. Since it is rarely possible to use these resources, I created this topic, perhaps for new candidate systems (there are euristic assumptions about identifying them) it will be possible to check the solvability faster with universal solvers, my method is essentially a sequential testing of variables.
